# "copy UV maps" not projecting properly

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

So I'm trying to copy the uv maps of multiple objects that are all the same I'm making the exact same knife cuts on them all so it works, and when I click ctrl + L then click copy uv maps the 2nd objects uvs look distorted. pic of original and copy:

[image]